# Formula Field on Timezone and DST

Tags: formula

I have a business use case that users would like to see if a lead is callable within local time zones. I created two pick lists that would do the trick, but I am running into compile limits.

Is there a way to refactor this within the compile limits? Or is there another option I fail to see?

### Time Zone Offset Formula

```
IF(

AND( 
TODAY() >= 
CASE(MOD(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8) - DATE(1900,1,7),7), 
0, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8), 
1, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8)+6, 
2, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8)+5, 
3, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8)+4, 
4, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8)+3, 
5, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8)+2, 
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),3,8)+1), 
TODAY() <
CASE(MOD(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1) - DATE(1900,1,7),7), 
0, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1), 
1, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1)+6, 
2, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1)+5, 
3, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1)+4, 
4, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1)+3, 
5, DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1)+2, 
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1)+1))
,

/*DST is true*/
CASE(  TimezonePicklist__c ,

"Atlantic", -3,
"Eastern", -4,
"Central", -5,
"Mountain", -6,
"Pacific", -7,
"Alaska", -8,
"Hawaii", -10,
0)


,
/*DST is False*/
CASE(  TimezonePicklist__c ,

"Atlantic", -4,
"Eastern", -5,
"Central", -6,
"Mountain", -7,
"Pacific", -8,
"Alaska", -9,
"Hawaii", -10,
0)

)
```

### Callable Field

````
CASE( Time_Zone_Offset_Formula__c,

0, "/img/samples/light_yellow.gif"

<0, 
CASE(Time_Zone_Offset_Formula__c + 24,
<8, "/img/samples/light_red.gif",
>21, "/img/samples/light_red.gif",
"/img/samples/light_yellow.gif"
),

<8, "/img/samples/light_red.gif",
>21, "/img/samples/light_red.gif",
"/img/samples/light_yellow.gif"
)
,
"/img/samples/light_yellow.gif"
)```
````